# URL Parameters for accessing files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my node.js project I have a server.js and a folder "views" that has a file called index.html, so right now when someone goes to `example.com` (or `example.com/index.html`) they go to index.js, well I'm trying to secure it so that only via specific links access is granted, for example

`example.com` -> takes you to access_denied.html
and
`example.com/client={code-that-i-assign}` example `example.com/client=th9wdn298n3d2`

I tried doing it with URLparams but I couldn't, can someone help me with a solution to this problem?

```js
function api() {
    const apikey = "";
    const searchselect = window.location.search;
    const urlsearchparams = URLSearchParams(searchselect);
    urlsearchparams.has(apikey).then(return true);

}
```

Comment: Would you be able to show us what you have so far?

Comment: sure, here https://pastebin.com/P1H1nDCu

Comment: Are you using express on your server-side?

Comment: Yes @NickParsons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to undertand that you want to check if there is a get variable in the url like a token for enter and use a determinate pages, for to do that you must use the express middleware before the the middleware that serve the page in your server.js file, like:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) { // controlla il token
  const foo = req.query.foo;

  if (foo !== 'MAGIC_KEY' /* or what control you want to do */) next(Error('Nope'));
  else next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and call the page whit this param `/?foo=MAGIC_KEY`

**EDIT with your code:**

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// make all the files in 'public' available
// https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static("public"));

// this is the code I writed before
app.use(function (req, res, next) { //  /?foo=MAGIC_KEY
  const foo = req.query.foo;

  if (foo !== 'MAGIC_KEY') next(Error('Nope'));
  else next();
});

// This is the middleware that serve the index
// https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/views/gg.txt")));

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Hey this isn't working this is my code --> https://pastebin.com/ZKQmK7vS It just takes me to index.js

Comment: In your code, you put the middleware after the middleware that serve index page.
I edit the answer with edit

Comment: It still doesn't work here's a GIF of what happens and I changed views with public https://gyazo.com/006fb582ef4f802c0bf8e9e308bbd379

Comment: After the change did you restart the server? 
I try using server.js with the code in the answer and an easy views/index.html.
When I call `localhost:3000/?foo=MAGIC_KEY` I see the page, where I don't use  `?foo=MAGIC_KEY` or I set a wrong `foo`value like `MAGIC_KEYs` the server returns me an error.

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/AlTheLazyMonkey/problemStack.git

Comment: That still doesn't work, here's what happens https://youtu.be/crVZZZ1FGnQ

Comment: ok, it's because you now use public folder no more views, sorry, I didn't understood.
Move `app.use(express.static("public"));` after the middleware with params control

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance, you could manage the requests one by one, however it usually isn't a great solution. Just replace `\key` to whatever you need. If you land on `example.com` it will respond with `access-denied.html`, however, requesting `example.com/key` for instance will get you to the index.

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// This is the middleware that serve the index
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/access-denied.html");
});

app.get("/key", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public/gg.txt")));

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```